# IntPtr Assigned variable is triggering 'Use of unassinged variable', Why is this happening?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Anyway, I am using example code to search for a device. However i have a compiler error "Use for unassigned local variable 'm_hObject'. 'm_hObject' is being assigned as a 'IntPtr' and i am not sure what the pointer is pointing to.

```
using CSnet;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public partial class Program
    {


        [DllImport("icsneo40.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 icsneoOpenNeoDevice(ref NeoDevice pNeoDevice, ref IntPtr hObject, ref byte bNetworkIDs, Int32 bConfigRead, Int32 bSyncToPC);

            static void Main()
            {
                IntPtr m_hObject; //handle for device
                int iResult; //Holds the results from function call
                NeoDevice ndNeoToOpen = new NeoDevice(); //Struct holding detected hardware information
                byte[] bNetwork = new byte[255]; //List of hardware IDs
                int iCount; //counter

                //File NetworkID array
                for (iCount = 0; iCount < 255; iCount++)
                {
                    bNetwork[iCount] = Convert.ToByte(iCount);
                }
                //Open the first found device, ndNeoToOpen acquired from FindNeoDevices 
                iResult = icsNeoDll.icsneoOpenNeoDevice(ref ndNeoToOpen, ref **m_hObject**, ref bNetwork[0], 1, 0);
                if (iResult == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Port Opened OK!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Problem Opening Port");
                    return;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing `ref` with `out` for `m_hObject` parameter. A `ref` parmeter is supposed to be initialized before being passed to a function; this requirement does not apply for an `out` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you use a variable without assigning something to it first.

```
    int x;
    int y = 30;

    int z = x + y;


    IntPtr x;
    IntPtr y = new IntPtr();

    IntPtr z = x.ToPointer();
```

in both blocks - you will get a compiler error of "Use of unassigned local variable 'x'"

In both cases, assign something to it

```
int x = 0;
IntPtr x = new IntPtr();
```

This code doesn't assume anything about icsneoOpenNeoDevice. Research that to see what it should be passed to it.

Comment: hmmm, I assumed it would point at the icsneoOpenNeoDevice an look for the device then pass the object. Let me look more into how this icsneoOpenNeoDevice works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IvannDRAGO it may indeed assign something to that parameter... It may not.. I don't know and that's why I pointed on that I wasn't assuming anything... However, your error is use of an unassigned variable... Assign something to it to get that compile error fixed.